# Lax-Milgram and the existence of solution to parabolic equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

I think it is standard and common to use Lax-Milgram theorem to prove the existence of solution to elliptic equation. However, can we use it to establish the existence of parabolic equation? I do not find some examples in standard PDE textbooks.

Suppose I have a parabolic equation
$$ \partial_t u - \partial_{x_j}(a_{ij} \partial_{x_i} u) + b_i \partial_{x_i} u + c u =f(x,t)$$
on $\Omega \times [0,T]$. Then the weak formulation should be
$$ \int_{\Omega} \partial_{t} u \varphi + a_{ij} \partial_{x_i} u \partial_{x_j} \varphi + b_i \partial_{x_i} u \varphi + c u \varphi-f\varphi=0,$$
for all $\varphi(x) \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and a.e. $t\in[0,T]$. But I do not know how can we define the bilinear mapping in this way. Or, is it impossible to prove the existence via Lax-Milgram? May I get some help? Thanks!

Comment: You might wish to have a look at the *Hille-Yosida theorem* and the *Lumer-Phillps theorem*.

Comment: More specifically, the proof of Theorem 5.7 in [these lecture notes](https://www.mat.tuhh.de/veranstaltungen/isem18/pdf/LectureNotes.pdf) from the [Internet Seminar on Evolution Equations](https://www.math.kit.edu/iana3/seite/isem/en) shows how the Lax-Milgram lemma can be used to prove well-posedness of parabolic equations. The proof essentially comes down to showing well-posedness of the elliptic problem - which is is hidden in the word "m-accretive" ini the proof - and then applying a generation theorem for semigroups, as indicated in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks! I will read it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the exact theorem from Chapter 3.1.2 in the book "Elliptic & Parabolic Equations" written by Zhuoqun Wu, Jingxue Yin and Chunpeng Wang.